# Where does pretty_print function come from if I pry Array in Ruby

Tags: c, ruby, arrays, pry

I'm playing around with pry and hit something that confuses me.

```
irb
pry
cd Array

pry(Array):>
```

`show-method` returns:

```
def pretty_print ...
def pretty_print_cycle ...
```

Where are those methods? I looked at the ruby Array from [Ruby Array doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html) and can't find the methods. I went to [search for array in github ruby project](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/search?q=array%20in%3Apath&type=Code) and saw Array.c and can't find Array.rb. Even then, I can't find pretty_print in Array.c.

Can someone help me understand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[].method(:pretty_print).source_location
=> ["/home/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pp.rb", 328]
```

Seems show-method gives this same information:

```
show-method [].pretty_print

From: /home/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pp.rb @ line 328:
Owner: Array
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 7

def pretty_print(q)
  q.group(1, '[', ']') {
    q.seplist(self) {|v|
      q.pp v
    }
  }
end
```

pry.rb requires pp:

https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/dd2d9b927b0afbe4e5463ff1558c566abbdb0473/lib/pry.rb

Answer (score 0):

Those methods aren't in the default `Array` implementation. Try, e.g., `[].pretty_print` in `irb` and you will get an error. The conclusion is that *pry* adds those methods to `Array`. In Ruby it is possible to add new methods to existing classes and objects, even built-in ones, e.g. (in `irb`):

```
> arr = [0,1,2]
> arr.pretty_print
NoMethodError: undefined method `pretty_print' for [0, 1, 2]:Array

> class Array
>   def pretty_print
>     "*** #{inspect} ***"
>   end
> end
> arr.pretty_print
 => "*** [0, 1, 2] ***"
```